# How can I pass fixtures to pytest.mark.parameterize?

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to pass three different fixtures to my `pytest.mark.parameterize` decorator, like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("credentials, return_code", [
    (user1, 200),
    #(user2, 200),
    #(user3, 401)
])
def test_login():
    assert True
# Actual test uses response.return_code == return_code
```

However, I get an error that reads:

```
NameError: name 'user1' is not defined
```

This isn't correct though, I have defined it in `conftest.py`:

```
user1_info = [('user1', 'password')]
@pytest.fixture(params=user1_info)
def user1(request):
    return request.param
```

---

The fixture works if I change my test to be like this:

```
def test_login(user1):
    assert True
# Actual test uses response.return_code == return_code
```

The problem is that if I do it this way, I have to write three separate tests, one for each fixture, and for each status_code check. If I could use `parameterize`, I could use one function and check the user/expected return code.

How can I utilize my fixtures are part of the `pytest.mark.parameterize` decorator?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To pass fixtures as parametrized arguments, reference them as strings and use the keyword arguments `indirect=['arg_name', ...]`.

Then use the parameter names `credentials` and `return_code` as arguments to your test function.

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "credentials, return_code",
    [
        ("user1", 200),
        ("user2", 200),
        ("user3", 401),
    ],
    # Only the `credentials` parameter is a reference to the
    # fixture. The `return_code` should be passed as is.
    indirect=["credentials"],
)
def test_login(credentials, return_code):
    return True
```

The documentation for pytest's `parametrize` magic with `indirect` can be found here:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#apply-indirect-on-particular-arguments

Comment: I have a test case with a similar structure. When I implement your suggestion I get an error saying *fixture 'return code' not found*. Apparently, setting indirect=True requires all parameters inside @pytest.mark.parametrize() to be function fixtures. Do you have an idea how to make @pytest.mark.parametrize() accommodate both function fixtures and parameters?

Comment: @merowinger Yes, you can apply indirect to specific arguments by passing a list of the indirect argument names to `indirect`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi @damon, in following the structure and the solution that you suggested, I am getting fixture credentials not found. Any idea why it is trying to look for credentials fixture even though I listed credentials in my indirect list?

Comment: @BICube `indirect` is a list of other fixtures to call. If you want to use the value directly, instead of calling a fixture with that name, don't include it in the `indirect` list.

Comment: This example appears to be incomplete. You still need a `credentials` fixture that translates the string `"userX"` to the `userX` object. Running this example as-is results in a `fixture 'credentials' not found` error message.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you can't. There are a few workarounds:

#### 1: forego parametrization

```py
def test_login():
    for user, return_code in [
      (User("user1", ...), 200),
      (User("user2", ...), 200),
      (User("user3", ...), 401),
    ]:
        # test user
        pass
```

or

```py
def test_login(user1, user2, user3):
    for user, return_code in [
      (user1, 200),
      (user2, 200),
      (user3, 401),
    ]:
        # test user
        pass
```

Pro: simple 
Con: If the first test fails, the later tests don't run. The error message also doesn't show which test case failed.

#### 2: parametrize with an index or name

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('idx', [0,1,2])
def test_login(idx):
    user, return_code = [
      (User("user1", ...), 200),
      (User("user2", ...), 200),
      (User("user3", ...), 401),
    ][idx]
        # test user
        pass
```

(or the equivalent using the `user1`, `user2`, `user3` fixtures)

Pro: pytest recognizes the separate tests 
Con: useless indexes/names

#### 3: use an indirect parametrization fixture

```py
@pytest.mark.fixture
def user_and_code(request):
    if request.param == "user1":
        return User("user1", ...), 200
    elif request.param == "user2":
        return User("user2", ...), 200
    elif request.param == "user3":
        return User("user3", ...), 401

@pytest.mark.parametrize('user_and_code', ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'], indirect=True)
def test_login(user_and_code):
    user, return_code = user_and_code

    # test user
    pass
```

Or

```py
@pytest.mark.fixture
def user_and_code(request, user1, user2, user3):
    return [
        (user1, 200),
        (user2, 200),
        (user3, 401),
    ][request.param]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('user_and_code', [0,1,2], indirect=True)
def test_login(user_and_code):
    user, return_code = user_and_code

    # test user
    pass
```

Pro: test code is clean, fixture can be reused in other tests 
Con: more complexity

According to the docs the indirect parametrization is meant to skip expensive setup during test collection, not so much to make fixtures available to parameters, which as you can see doesn't work very well.

There are a few choices that can be mixed and matched in each of the above options, e.g. instantiating all users or using if/else to only instantiate what you need, using the `user1` etc fixtures or creating users inline, using names or indexes, etc. The examples only show some of the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The [pytest-cases library](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-cases/) allows you to parametrize fixtures. A worked example:

```py
import pytest_cases

@pytest_cases.fixture()
def one():
    return 1

@pytest_cases.fixture()
def two():
    return 2

@pytest_cases.parametrize("number", (one, two))
def test_it(number):
    assert number in [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios that you might encounter here:

## 1. I have a static fixture that I want to pass into a parameterized test

With this, you simply pass the fixture(s) in as the last argument(s) in your test function:

```py
import pytest 

@pytest.fixture
def myfixture():
    return 'world'


@pytest.mark.parametrize('hello', ['Hello', 'HELLO'])
def test_world(hello, myfixture):
    output = hello.lower() + myfixture 
    assert output == 'helloworld'
```

## 2. I have a fixture that I want to match by name

Pass the `request` fixture and look up the one you want using `getfixturevalue`:

```py
import pytest 

@pytest.fixture
def a():
    return 'a'

@pytest.fixture
def b():
    return 'b'


@pytest.mark.parametrize('fixture_name', ['a', 'b'])
def test_fixture_lookup(fixture_name, request):
    output = request.getfixturevalue(fixture_name)
    assert fixture_name == output
```