# How to pass a fixture that returns a variable-length iterable of values to pytest.mark.parameterize?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a pytest fixture that produces an iterable and I would like to parameterize a test using the items in this iterable, but I cannot figure out the correct syntax.

Does anyone know how to parametrize a test using the values of a fixture? Here is some dummy code that shows my current approach:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def values():
    return [1, 1, 2]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('value', values)
def test_equal(value):
    assert value == 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass fixtures to pytest.mark.parameterize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47726000/how-can-i-pass-fixtures-to-pytest-mark-parameterize)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't. The fixture I want to pass to `pytest.mark.parameterize` is a single large iterable that can be of variable length, so creating an iterable of separate fixtures does not work in my case.

Comment: Sorry if that link wasn't clear, but the point was not to make "separate fixtures" but more about using the `parametrize`'s `indirect=` parameter, which "lazily" evaluates the values from a fixture. To confirm, you don't know _beforehand_ the size/length of the `values` list/iterable? Because you could make that fixture accept an index argument and just `indirect`-ly return 1 value at a time. If the length isn't known _beforehand_ (something that could be [edit] -ed into the question), then that makes it tricky. I've retracted my close vote either way.

Comment: Not a direct duplicate since this question doesn't mention `pytest_generate_hook`, but since our answers here suggest using that hook, this might be related: [Is it possible to use a fixture inside pytest_generate_tests()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59309558/2745495) (TL;DR: no, it's not possible either.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is [pytest doesn't support passing fixtures to `parametrize`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349).

The out-of-the-box solution provided by pytest is to either use [`indirect` parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization) or define your own parametrization scheme using [`pytest_generate_tests`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/parametrize.html#pytest-generate-tests) as described in [How can I pass fixtures to pytest.mark.parameterize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47726000/how-can-i-pass-fixtures-to-pytest-mark-parameterize)

These are the workarounds I've used before to solve this problem.

#### Option 1: Separate function for generating `values`

```
from typing import Iterator, List
import pytest

def generate_values() -> Iterator[str]:
    # ... some computationally-intensive operation ...
    all_possible_values = [1, 2, 3]
    for value in all_possible_values:
        yield value

@pytest.fixture()
def values() -> List[str]:
    return list(generate_values())

def test_all_values(values):
    assert len(values) > 5

@pytest.mark.parametrize("value", generate_values())
def test_one_value_at_a_time(value: int):
    assert value == 999
```

```
$ pytest -vv tests
...
========================================================== short test summary info ===========================================================
FAILED tests/test_main.py::test_all_values - assert 3 > 5
FAILED tests/test_main.py::test_one_value_at_a_time[1] - assert 1 == 999
FAILED tests/test_main.py::test_one_value_at_a_time[2] - assert 2 == 999
FAILED tests/test_main.py::test_one_value_at_a_time[3] - assert 3 == 999
```

The main change is moving the generation of the list of values to a regular, non-fixture function `generate_values`. If it's a static list, then you can even forego making it a function and just define it as a regular module-level variable.

```
ALL_POSSIBLE_VALUES = [1, 2, 3]
```

Not everything always needs to be a fixture. It's advantageous for injecting the test data into functions, yes, but it doesn't mean you can't use regular Python functions and variables. The only problem with this solution is if generating the list of values depends on other fixtures, i.e. [reusable fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#fixtures-are-reusable). In that case, you would have to re-define those as well.

I've kept the `values` fixture here for tests where you do need to get *all* the possible values as a list, like in `test_all_values`.

If this list of values is going to be used for multiple other tests, instead of decorating with `parametrize` for each one, you can do that in the [`pytest_generate_tests`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/parametrize.html#pytest-generate-tests) hook.

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc: pytest.Metafunc):
    if "value" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("value", generate_values())

def test_one_value_at_a_time(value: int):
    assert value == 999
```

This option avoids a lot of duplication and you can then even change `generate_values` to whatever or however you need it to be independently of the tests and the testing framework.

#### Option 2: Use `indirect` and let fixture return 1 value at a time

If it's possible to know the length of the list of values *beforehand* (as in before running the tests), you can then use `parametrize`'s `indirect=` and then let the fixture only return one value at a time.

```
# Set/Defined by some env/test configuration?
MAX_SUPPORTED_VALUES = 5

@pytest.fixture
def value(request: pytest.FixtureRequest) -> int:
    all_possible_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    selected_index = request.param
    return all_possible_values[selected_index]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("value", range(MAX_SUPPORTED_VALUES), indirect=True)
def test_one_value_at_a_time(value: int):
    assert value == 999
```

The main change is letting the fixture accept a parameter (an index), and then returning the value at that index. (Also renaming the fixture from `values` to `value` to match the return value). Then, in the test, you use [`indirect=True`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html?#indirect-parametrization) and then pass a range of indices, which is passed to the fixture as `request.param`.

**Again, this only works if you know at least the length of the list of values.**

Also, again, instead of applying the `parametrize` decorator for each test that uses this fixture, you can use `pytest_generate_tests`:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc: pytest.Metafunc):
    if "value" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("value", range(MAX_SUPPORTED_VALUES), indirect=True)

def test_one_value_at_a_time(value: int):
    assert value == 999
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a conftest file, move your fixture, modify them, and then finally add one more function :)

First file:

```
# content of the test_<your_filename>.py

def test_equal(values):
   assert values == 1
```

Second file:

```
# content of the conftest.py

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
   if "values" in metafunc.fixturenames:
       metafunc.parametrize("values", [1, 2, 3], indirect=True)


@pytest.fixture
def values(request):
   return request.param
```

`request` in the fixture is `_pytest.fixtures.SubRequest` instance. And `param` is parameter from the list in `pytest_generate_tests`.

And the test output:

```
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /mnt/d/temp
collected 3 items

test_aa.py .FF                                                     [100%]

================================ FAILURES ================================
______________________________ test_equal[2] _____________________________

    def test_equal(values):
>       assert values == 1
E       assert 2 == 1

test_aa.py:3: AssertionError
______________________________ test_equal[3] _____________________________
values = 3

    def test_equal(values):
>       assert values == 1
E       assert 3 == 1

test_aa.py:3: AssertionError
======================== short test summary info ========================
FAILED test_aa.py::test_equal[2] - assert 2 == 1
FAILED test_aa.py::test_equal[3] - assert 3 == 1
====================== 2 failed, 1 passed in 0.97s ======================
```

More details and examples you find in [this part](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html#deferring-the-setup-of-parametrized-resources) of pytest documentation.

Comment: "*`request` in the fixture is `_pytest.fixtures.SubRequest`*" The documented API reference is here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#request. I find that `pytest.FixtureRequest` is more helpful when used as a type hint.